# Google Analytics is excluding traffic from my view

Tags: google-analytics, seo, web-analytics

I'm trying to remove 'Ghost Referral Spam' from my Google Analytics, and have been following advice for setting up filters to block this type of traffic. The first filter people suggest is to *include* only traffic to your *hostname*.

However, this filter is being problematic, and is blocking most of my genuine traffic too.

I'm aware these filters take 24-48 hours to become effective, and do not work retroactively. But this is not the problem:

The filtered view has been running for 30 days: it contains far less traffic than the unfiltered view, even when I segment the unfiltered view on hostname (which in theory should produce the same dataset).

To reiterate: comparing the `hostname` filtered view alongside an unfiltered view segmented by the same `hostname` displays different results!

Why is traffic not making it into my view?

---

[image]

Comment: Just at first glance, you are setting the filter only for the "www" subdomain. Is that intentional? Or do you want the filter to include any other subdomains or even just "example.com"?

Comment: It's the only subdomain in use right now. I've confirmed that in the Audience > Technology > Network section too.

Comment: One thing about including legit traffic in a filter is that you need to also include legit sources where you know you get traffic from, for example youtube, or other Google sources, and not just from www.example.com. So, just to confirm, you can't get to your site from just "example.com" (without the www)?

Comment: I guarantee the traffic it's dropping is going to www.example.com - since segmenting on that hostname against the unfiltered view reveals more traffic than the filtered view. Both, in theory, should display the same traffic (whether it's filtering through a segment, or a filtered view). Re. your first point: yes, that's a legitimate concern that I'll need to address separately :)

Comment: Do you have any other include hostname filters?

Comment: No other filters. This is the only one.

Comment: No idea if that will solve your problem but since this is a regular expression you should escape your dots ("." is a special character in regex that means "match any character") with a  \backslash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Misconfiguration on my part - turns out I had 'User-ID Tracking' enabled, so it was only showing registered users on my site.

I discovered this by stepping through every setting in my unfiltered view, and comparing it against the filtered view. Not sure how this happened.

In hindsight, I should have just created a copy of the unfiltered view (there's a button to do this), and then apply the filter, knowing that everything else would be the same.